# Django Channels await database_to_async method not working

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, django-channels

I'm trying to build a notification application by using Django Channels.
The problem I'm having is the following error:

> django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.

consumers.py

```
class NotificationConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    @database_sync_to_async
    def get_notifications(self, user):
        new_messages = NotificationSerializer(Notification.objects.filter(content=1, users_notified__in=[user]), many=True)

        notifs = {
            "new_messages": new_messages
        }

        return notifs

    async def connect(self):
        user = self.scope["user"]

        if user:
            self.channel_name = user.username
            self.room_group_name = 'notification_%s' % self.channel_name
            
            # Error happens in the following line
            notification = await self.get_notifications(self.scope["user"])
            print("Notification", notification)

            await self.channel_layer.group_add(
                self.room_group_name,
                self.channel_name
            )

            await self.accept()
        
        await self.disconnect(401)
    
    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    async def notify(self, event):
        await self.send_json(event["content"])
```

I have used the exact same approach when I developed a Django Channels chat application that saves messages to the database as well. When trying to convert my approach to the Notification system, it doesn't anymore.

As soon as I don't await the `self.get_notifications` method anymore, it works but I only get back a `<coroutine object SyncToAsync.__call__ at ...>`